# Displaying an event stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selectedEvent = null;
        let eventsArr = loadData();
        let calendar = initCalendar();

        $('#btnEdit').click(function () {  
            $('#viewEvent').modal('hide');    
        });

        $('#btnDelete').click(function () {    
        });
    
        function loadData() {
            let eventsArr = [];
            let eventTable = document.getElementById("eventTable");
            let trElem = eventTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (let tr of trElem) {    
                let tdElems = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
                let eventObj = {
                    id: tdElems[0].innerText,
                    title: tdElems[1].innerText,
                    start: tdElems[2].innerText,
                    end: tdElems[3].innerText,
                    description: tdElems[4].innerText   
                }
                eventsArr.push(eventObj);
            }
            return eventsArr;
        }

        function initCalendar() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#378006',
                events: eventsArr,
                eventDisplay: true                 
            });  
            calendar.render();
            return calendar;
        }   
    });        
</script>
```

I need help displaying these events to the fullcalendar. The events come from me entering them in a form and then they will be displayed in the calendar.

Right now the events only display in the top of the calendar but not on the calendar.

Comment: What do you mean by "only in the top", exactly? It's not clear. Can we have a screenshot? Also can you give a sample of the event data you're entering please? Thankyou.

Comment: You need to include the basic HTML structure that this script is populating, because as written this question asks us to guess. Also, side note, while it's allowed and possible to mix jQuery code with DOM methods (`document.getElementById`, etc.) why would you? jQuery is there to make all of that easier on you.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole I don't think we need any HTML here, but we do certainly need a screenshot of the output the OP is getting, and also the data contained in `eventsArr`.